# Encoding problems in Java File

Tags: java, character-encoding, diacritics

I have String in java which is filename containing umlauts. File is stored on Win 7 Pro disk correctly (umlauts etc. are shown correctly in explorer file listing). I also tried to save filename to text file and then filename was correctly outputted with umlauts. But when I use method exists() from File, it says file doesn't exists. If I try to use method createNewFile(), it creates file like Ã¤.txt (originally ä.txt). What could be wrong in my settings here? I'm using Tomcat 6 and Eclipse to run my web application.

Comment: What are the encoding settings in the Eclipse project properties ?

Comment: Is the file name hard coded in your code or do you read it from somewhere?

Comment: @Robert It's read from http request, but if i write that string to text file, then it is correctly printed, so it cannot be related to that.

Comment: @SoboLAN I tried default Cp1252 and UTF-8 and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you start java with the proprty -Dfile.encoding=whatever ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file name would be included as static constant in your source code it would not make a difference where your code is being executed, but as you are reading the filename from an remote address it makes a significant difference.

By default every Java instance as a default charset on Windows this is usually "Cp1252", on other systems usually "UTF-8". Therefore every method that is reading or writing Strings from/to network or file system the default charset is used - as long as you don't use the method versions where the charset is explicitly specified.

Therefore writing the file-name into a file doesn't demonstrates everything because if it is displayed correctly depends on the text editor you are using not on the Java program writing it.

Conclusion: Go through your code and make sure you explicitly set the charset. This is especially relevant for methods `getBytes()` of String and every where you have a Reader/Writer instance connected to an InputStream/OutpuStream.